# trouble with friendly forwarding in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, email

This is sort of a follow up to this [trouble with email with one click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264325/trouble-with-email-with-one-click).

I'm having trouble with friendly forwarding.  See my code below and my website http://fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com/.  I'm not sure why it's not working.  When I type something into the textarea and click send, it successfully sends me the email, but I get

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

The url this comes from is `http://fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com/application_controller/email`.

What can I do to fix this?

---

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :store_location

  def email
    UserMailer.idea_bar(params[:message]).deliver
    redirect_back
  end

  def redirect_back
    redirect_to(session[:return_to])
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

logs

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku logs -n 100
2013-06-24T21:55:48.255770+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 21:55:48 +0000
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261042+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/application_controller/email"):
2013-06-24T21:55:48.260811+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:55:48.261203+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:55:48.306826+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=43ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-06-24T21:57:47.069917+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7c0f200 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T21:57:47.087176+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v39 created by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T21:57:47.134694+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 7c0f200 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T21:57:49.922216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 46014`
2013-06-24T21:57:47.242266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-24T21:57:52.045156+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T21:57:52.045156+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T21:57:52.183084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-24T21:57:53.243439+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2013-06-24T21:57:53.243439+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 21:57:53] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-24T21:57:53.789109+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-24T21:57:53.789109+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-24T21:57:53.789109+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:46014
2013-06-24T21:57:53.789109+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutd
own server
2013-06-24T21:57:53.789109+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-24T21:57:53.961606+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 21:57:53] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-24T21:57:53.961942+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 21:57:53] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=46014
2013-06-24T21:57:53.961606+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 21:57:53] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-24T21:57:54.402996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-24T21:57:55.409537+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/colleges" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 21:57:55 +0000
2013-06-24T21:57:55.653227+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#colleges as HTML
2013-06-24T21:57:55.721500+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 68ms (Views: 65.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-06-24T21:57:55.718280+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/colleges.html.erb within layouts/application (10.3ms)
2013-06-24T21:57:56.031720+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/colleges-7adcb0138796cf2dd39ad973ccd58699.css host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=232
2013-06-24T21:57:56.021391+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/layout-eae006a3ffc93619e067580f95bb8a9a.css host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=1643
2013-06-24T21:57:56.064409+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-e432bc54db845c729a762e0d298d3579.js host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=156605
2013-06-24T21:58:00.238260+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MubEQddsKvR/QBLZtZKCt8TF9EiUSHjSTpxtSB5mAhE=", "message"=>"nanana", "email"=>""}
2013-06-24T21:58:00.233387+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 21:58:00 +0000
2013-06-24T21:58:00.238260+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#email as HTML
2013-06-24T21:58:01.163235+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:58:01.163235+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to azerner3@gmail.com (883ms)
2013-06-24T21:58:01.163553+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 925ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-06-24T21:58:01.163409+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com/application_controller/email
2013-06-24T21:58:01.163563+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=946ms status=302 bytes=133
2013-06-24T21:58:01.259335+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 21:58:01 +0000
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/application_controller/email"):
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.262888+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.
1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263058+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263207+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2013-06-24T21:58:01.263541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=728
2013-06-24T21:58:02.470905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-24T21:58:02.470526+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-24T21:58:04.905915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-24T21:57:55.723090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/colleges host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=329ms status=200 bytes=13015
2013-06-24T21:55:39.452235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

---

I'm also having trouble with having the user have the option to put their email in the text_field and use it in :reply_to.  I'm getting a `We're sorry, but something went wrong` error.  Here's my code.

application_controller.rb

```
def email
  UserMailer.idea_bar(params[:message, :email]).deliver
  redirect_back
end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "anonymous@collegeanswers.com", to: "azerner3@gmail.com", subject: "collegeanswers"

  def idea_bar(message, email)
    mail(:body => message, :reply_to => email)
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<div class="idea_bar">
            <div class="left_idea_bar">
                <p>Ideas, comments, questions, suggestions?  Help us help you!</p>
                <%= form_tag("/application_controller/email", :method => "post", :id => "idea_bar_form") do %>
                    <%= text_area_tag('message', nil, :size => "60x4", :id => "message", :name => "message") %> <br />
                    <%= label_tag(:email, "• include your email if you want a response:") %>
                    <%= text_field_tag(:email, nil, :id => "email", :size => "36", :name => "email") %>
            </div>
                    <button id="submit" type="submit" form="idea_bar_form"><span id="big_submit">Send</span>
                    <span id="small_submit"><br />&#8226 one click<br />&#8226 anonymous</span></button>
                <% end %>
        </div>
```

logs

```
~/collegeanswerz >>  heroku logs -n 100
2013-06-24T22:13:22.070506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-24T22:13:22.058613+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#email as HTML
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:13:22.053895+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 22:13:22 +0000
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:13:22.058613+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MubEQddsKvR/QBLZtZKCt8TF9EiUSHjSTpxtSB5mAhE=", "message"=>"hut!", "email"=>"adam@aol.com"}
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:13:22.059587+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (undefined local variable or method `email' for #<UserMailer:0x000000031eaf48>):
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:5:in `idea_bar'
2013-06-24T22:13:22.061282+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `email'
2013-06-24T22:12:59.249471+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-e432bc54db845c729a762e0d298d3579.js host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=156605
2013-06-24T22:10:26.295440+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="84.221.243.223" dyno=web.1 connect=7ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=17199
2013-06-24T22:19:39.441731+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8e1cec3 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:19:39.477546+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v41 created by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:19:39.531576+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8e1cec3 by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:19:39.941429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-24T22:19:42.805719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 43608`
2013-06-24T22:19:44.139921+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:19:44.973360+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:19:44] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:19:44.973360+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2013-06-24T22:19:45.605144+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T22:19:45.605144+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T22:19:48.529969+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-24T22:19:48.529969+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-24T22:19:48.529969+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-24T22:19:48.529969+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-24T22:19:48.529969+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:43608
2013-06-24T22:19:48.732635+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:19:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-24T22:19:48.732635+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:19:48] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-24T22:19:48.734523+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:19:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=43608
2013-06-24T22:19:49.001422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-24T22:19:49.922369+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 22:19:49 +0000
2013-06-24T22:19:50.226541+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
2013-06-24T22:19:50.302550+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (4.3ms)
2013-06-24T22:19:50.298964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=407ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-06-24T22:19:50.302550+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 75ms (Views: 74.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-06-24T22:19:50.583859+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/home-73d942132cfdcc305dabf385494f8201.css host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=21ms status=200 bytes=1884
2013-06-24T22:19:50.586706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-e432bc54db845c729a762e0d298d3579.js host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=156605
2013-06-24T22:19:50.566000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/layout-eae006a3ffc93619e067580f95bb8a9a.css host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=1643
2013-06-24T22:19:53.719509+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:19:53.719746+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-24T22:19:55.941278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-24T22:20:00.163148+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 22:20:00 +0000
2013-06-24T22:20:00.168154+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#email as HTML
2013-06-24T22:20:00.168154+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MubEQddsKvR/QBLZtZKCt8TF9EiUSHjSTpxtSB5mAhE=", "message"=>"hut hut!", "email"=>"adam@aol.com"}
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `[]'
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `email'
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:20:00.173480+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=102ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-24T22:20:00.173650+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-06-24T22:20:00.175287+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments(2 for 1)):
2013-06-24T22:19:53.004668+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-24T22:22:12.058084+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 40eed1a by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:22:12.108863+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v42 created by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:22:12.155875+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 40eed1a by arz21@pitt.edu
2013-06-24T22:22:12.270402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-06-24T22:22:16.267852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 22639`
2013-06-24T22:22:17.704632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:22:18.623078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:22:18] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:22:18.623078+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2013-06-24T22:22:24.952722+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T22:22:24.959495+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-06-24T22:22:25.830874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2013-06-24T22:22:25.830693+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2013-06-24T22:22:28.152731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-06-24T22:22:32.214155+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-06-24T22:22:32.214155+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-06-24T22:22:32.214155+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-06-24T22:22:32.214155+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-06-24T22:22:32.214155+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:22639
2013-06-24T22:22:33.099572+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:22:33] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=22639
2013-06-24T22:22:33.097934+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:22:33] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-05-15) [x86_64-linux]
2013-06-24T22:22:33.097697+00:00 app[web.1]: [2013-06-24 22:22:33] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2013-06-24T22:22:33.217359+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-06-24T22:22:35.024045+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 22:22:35 +0000
2013-06-24T22:22:35.164459+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=98ms status=200 bytes=0
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `email'
2013-06-24T22:22:35.796508+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#email as HTML
2013-06-24T22:22:35.800261+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments(2 for 1)):
2013-06-24T22:22:35.796508+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MubEQddsKvR/QBLZtZKCt8TF9EiUSHjSTpxtSB5mAhE=", "message"=>"hut hut hut", "email"=>"adam@aol.com"}
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `[]'
2013-06-24T22:22:35.801723+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:35.791412+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=8ms service=816ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-06-24T22:22:36.044223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=29ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-06-24T22:22:40.763396+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/application_controller/email" for 150.212.84.228 at 2013-06-24 22:22:40 +0000
2013-06-24T22:22:40.768169+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ApplicationController#email as HTML
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `email'
2013-06-24T22:22:40.769416+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 0ms
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:40.768169+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MubEQddsKvR/QBLZtZKCt8TF9EiUSHjSTpxtSB5mAhE=", "message"=>"hut hut hut", "email"=>"adam@aol.com"}
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments(2 for 1)):
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `[]'
2013-06-24T22:22:40.771820+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-06-24T22:22:40.756072+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/application_controller/email host=fast-reaches-9399.herokuapp.com fwd="150.212.84.228" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=643
~/collegeanswerz >>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the location inside the session on each request, so when you're redirecting back in the email action, the user is redirected back to the email action, though via GET this time. Stop saving the location for the email action and everything will work.

-- EDIT: about the reply_to --

Inside your application_controller.rb, the email action should look like this:

```
def email
  UserMailer.idea_bar(params[:message], params[:email]).deliver
  redirect_back
end
```

Comment: thanks so much.  could you look at the edit to my question as well?  I'm having trouble with reply_to.